# Plural subject but singular object

Tags: grammatical-number

I've seen a few helpful posts on this, and understand that there is no rule necessarily, but I'm trying to wrap my head around something like the following example:

"For the purposes of Chapter 3, the following terms, phrases, words, and their derivatives shall have the meaning stated below."

From what I've read, the singular of "meaning" would be appropriate if *all* the terms, words, phrases, etc., shared the same meaning. But what follows is a list of definitions of many terms. I can't quite put my finger on why "meaning" sounds OK, but would "meanings" be preferable? Or is "meaning" collectively OK because they're *all* defined below in a collective list of definitions?

Comment: Arguably neither is grammatically wrong, as compare say 'they all turned their back on him',  but 'meanings' is more logical.

Comment: And, it being more logical, I would edit it to “meanings” were I to encounter such a construction.